# How do I get Javascript arrays from database response instead of pain Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongoose-schema

I've been banging my head against this for a while and would appreciate any help.I'm querying a MongoDB database which has arrays embedded into the document schema. Here is the schema:

```
const segmentSchema = new Schema({
    author: String, //Email address
    content: String,                                                                                            
    order: Number
})

const storySchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    isPublic: Boolean,
    complete: Boolean,
    segments: [segmentSchema],
    segCount: Number,
    lastUpdate: Date,
    locked: Boolean,
    rounds: Number,
    authors: [String]
})
```

When I get the results back, the data is there, but when I try to do array-specific functions I get errors. Here's the context:

```
fetch(`/api/stories/${props.storyID}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(theStory => {
          theStory.authors.foreach(auth => {
            console.log(auth);
          }
})
        .catch(err => {
          let errorArray = [`Sorry, there was an issue loading the story: ${err}`];
          console.log('Issue loading story: ', err);
          setErrors(errorArray);
        }
```

I've tried every which way to get these into arrays so that I can use functions like foreach and .map etc, but no luck. I thought they should just come back as arrays as they're arrays in the schema, and when I add them to the database, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `Content-Type` header from your request because `GET` requests don’t have a body.

Comment: It’s `forEach` not `foreach`.

Comment: You should provide your BE response. There is a gap in your example. The issue potentially exists inside your controller.

Comment: You need to gracefully handle non-200 and non-JSON responses in your promise chain otherwise it will blow-up with no useful clue as to what’s gone wrong.